# DOMDocument::loadHTML() - with external Javascript

Tags: php, laravel, dom, instagram-api

I am getting data from Instagram's [oEmbed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/). I am receiving this API response:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "author_name": "diegoquinteiro",
  "provider_name": "Instagram",
  "provider_url": "https://www.instagram.com/",
  "type": "rich",
  "width": 658,
  "html": "<blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-ca...",
  "thumbnail_width": 640,
  "thumbnail_height": 640
}
```

For the `html` key, I wanted to load it using `DOMDocument::loadHTML()`, so this is my code:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($data['html']);
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't fully render the page, because the `html` value has a `<script async src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>` but it doesn't execute that script.

Is there a way to fully render the page, like execute the javascript at the bottom, then I'll start to parse the HTML. I'm doing a `DOMXPath` to parse those HTMLs.

By the way this is the whole value of the `html` key from Instagram's API response:

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/ can help you.

Comment: The other, common keyword for stuff like this would be _headless browser_.